# in method problems in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I was trying to find as a dictionary (JS object) how many times each of the elements appears in some list. For example, the appearance of 1 in the list [1,1,2,2,1,3,4] is 3, because there are three ones in the list. In python I would implement this in the following way:

```
l = [1,1,2,2,1,3,4]
apr = dict()

for e in l:
    if (e in apr.keys()):
        apr[e] += 1
    else:
        apr[e] = 1
```

In javascript I decided to do

```
var arr = [1,1,2,2,1,3,4];

var vals = {};

for (let e of arr){
    if (e in Object.keys(vals)){        
        vals[e] = vals[e] + 1;
    }
    else{
        
        vals[e] = 1;
    }
}

// vals = { '1': 2, '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1 }
```

which is obviously wrong. Then I tried `if (Object.keys(vals).includes(e)){` instead, and it didn't work either. At the very end I implemented my own function `my_in`, and the progem worked:

```
function my_in(val,arr){
    for (i = 0; i<=arr.length; i++){
        if (val==arr[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var arr = [1,1,2,2,1,3,4];

var vals = {};

for (let e of arr){
    //if (Object.keys(vals).includes(e)){
    // if (e in Object.keys(vals)){
    if (my_in(e, Object.keys(vals))) {
        
        vals[e] = vals[e] + 1;
    }
    else{
        
        vals[e] = 1;
    }
}

console.log(vals);
```

But I am still confused why did the first two tries didn't work. Is there anything I should be aware of when using `in` or `includes()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) with the object, not with an array this would check the indices.

For example by using an an array of keys

```
vals = { 1: 1 }
keys = Object(vals) // ['1']

if (1 in keys) performs 
-> 1 in { 0: 1, length: 1 }, because there is only index zero with value one
-> false
```

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4];
var vals = {};

for (let e of arr) {
    if (e in vals) {           // check with object
        vals[e] = vals[e] + 1;
    } else {
        vals[e] = 1;
    }
}

console.log(vals);
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I wanted to check if e appears not in keys, but in values (in some other case)?

Comment: then take `Object.values(object).includes(someValue)`.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain why didn't  if (e in Object.keys(vals)){  didn't work then?

Comment: @DaniyarAubekerov Because as Nina stated, the `in` operator has to be used with an object, not an array. `Object.keys(...)` and `Object.values(...)` both return an array of the keys or values respectively, thus making them unusable for the `in` operator.

Comment: @MauriceNino, but ```if (Object.keys(vals).includes(e)){``` didn't work either, even though I used ```.includes``` with array. Sorry if that sounds stupid.

Comment: @DaniyarAubekerov Thats because of a JS quirk. Basically your keys in an object are of type `String`. Your variable `e` is of type `Number`. `.includes(...)` does a check with `===` which not only checks for value, but also for type, so `1 === '1' is false` rather than your desired `1 == '1' is true`. Do you understand what I mean? You could have used `if (Object.keys(vals).some(val => val == e)){`. Note the `==` check in this example. More info on `some`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 1):

The `Object.keys(object)` function returns an array of the string keys in the object.

When you do `if (e in Object.keys(vals))` this would actually check the `e` element in the array returned from the `Object.keys` call. Which is not what you want.

You should simply check the presence of the `e` key in the `vals` object, if present increment by 1 else assign `0` to it:

```js
var arr = [1,1,2,2,1,3,4];

var vals = {};

for (let e of arr){
   vals[e] = (vals[e] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log(vals)
```

The issue with your code was, when you did `Object.keys(vals)` for the first iteration it returned an empty array `[]` as `vals` was an empty object `{}`. So `e in Object.keys(vals)` was `false` and it went to the `else` block. In the `else` block the `vals[e] = 1` was executed.

In the next iteration when the check `e in Object.keys(vals)` happened it was evaluated to `true` as the array `["1"]` was returned because `vals` is `{1: 1}`, same for the other elements so that is why you see `{1: 2, 2: 1...}`.